# Amazon Echo app with login

Tags: authentication, amazon-echo

I tried to develope simple app for Amazon echo and it's working. Now I want to create app with login but have no idea how to start.
How can I set up login into Alexa app on phone? I mean when you install new skill there should be login screen (for example like in Uber skill).

Any ideas?

Comment: Learn PHP, Learn how to use PDO/MySQLi and prepared statements, learn how to avoid SQL attacks. Happy coding :)

Comment: @virtualAnon such an intelligent answer...

Comment: What basically programming language you're gonna use? Sorry but that only applies on Web Developing.

Comment: In my app I use javascript. Data will be stored in mysql database. I would like to use facebook login for my app but have no idea where to start to put login into Alexa phone app

Answer (score 1):

You user will have to link their Amazon account/Echo to your app using the Alexa application.  When they add your skill to the list of skills their Echo uses, they can connect to your service with a username/pw.

Note this means they do not login each time - they connect to your service once, then your skill will get their userID with the Alexa payload so you can identify who it is.  You won't be prompting them each time for a username and password.

Check details here: https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/linking-an-alexa-user-with-a-user-in-your-system